# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement') with writeValue angular function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous

I'm working on an angular application, which has an architecture with pre-defined classes I need to follow. I'm showing a list of addresses and I'm adding CRUD functionality.

The problem I'm encountering is when editing an address. The data to populate the dropdownlist comes via an API call to the .Net core backend. I think that the problem I'm encountering is has something to with data/properties being accessed prior to the data arriving from the backend. The problem is, when getting the error the dropdownlist with countries and cities do get populated, but the correct value (the country and city of the record being edited) isn't selected automatically.

I get this error after I click the edit button. What's funny is that when the edit window is already open, and i click edit again, all works fine without errors. The correct value is selected from the dropdowns as well, as it should.

the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement')
    at push.wnGv.SelectComponent.writeValue (select.component.ts:42:6)
    at shared.ts:122:24
    at model.ts:1188:25
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at FormControl.setValue (model.ts:1187:22)
    at model.ts:1520:27
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at FormGroup.setValue (model.ts:1518:24)
    at NgForm.setValue (ng_form.ts:283:18)
    at eloket-form.ts:10:5
```

Angular code:
adres-form.component.ts:

```
export interface FlowbackPersoneelslidAdresForm {

  straatLijn: string;
  straatLijn2: string;
  nummer: number;
  bus: number;
  codeGemeente: CodeGemeente;
  codeAdresType: CodeAdrestype;
  codeLand: CodeLand;
  //isPrive: boolean;
  isCorrespondentie: boolean;
  beginDatum: moment.Moment;
  eindDatum: moment.Moment;
  attest: any;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-adres-form',
  templateUrl: './adres-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./adres-form.component.scss']
})

export class AdresFormComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('f', { static: true }) FlowbackPersoneelslidAdresForm: EloketForm<FlowbackPersoneelslidAdresForm>;

  @Input() serverValidationError: ValidationBag;

  @Input() submitButtonText: string;

  @Input() set flowBackPersoneelslidAdres(value: FlowbackPersoneelslidAdres) {
    if (!value) {
      return;
    }
    console.log('before setFormValue, value passed to setFormValue:', value);
    console.log(value.codeAdresType);
    setFormValue(this.FlowbackPersoneelslidAdresForm, {
      straatLijn: value.straat,
      straatLijn2: value.straatLijn2,
      nummer: value.huisNummer,
      bus: value.busNummer,
      codeAdresType: value.codeAdresType,
      codeGemeente: value.codeGemeente,
      codeLand: value.codeLand,
      beginDatum: moment(value.beginDatum),
      eindDatum: moment(value.eindDatum),
      isCorrespondentie: value.isCorrespondentie,
      //isPrive: value.isPrive,
      attest: value.flowbackPersoneelslidAdresAttest
    });
    if (value.flowbackPersoneelslidAdresAttest) {
      this.attestAanwezig = true;
      this.attest = new FlowbackPersoneelslidAdresAttest(value.flowbackPersoneelslidAdresAttest);
    }
  }

  @Output() public flowbackPersoneelslidAdresChange = new EventEmitter<FlowbackPersoneelslidAdresForm>();

  //defaults to current date
  minDateActiefVanaf: moment.Moment = moment(new Date());
  codeAdrestypeSelectConfig: ModelSelectConfig<CodeAdrestype>;
  codeAdrestypes: CodeAdrestype[];

  codeGemeenteSelectConfig: ModelSelectConfig<CodeGemeente>;
  codeGemeenten: CodeGemeente[];

  codeLandSelectConfig: ModelSelectConfig<CodeLand>;
  codeLanden: CodeLand[];

  fileToUpload: File = null;
  attestAanwezig: boolean = false;
  attest: FlowbackPersoneelslidAdresAttest;
  loaded: boolean = false;

  constructor(private confirmationService: ConfirmationService, private codeTabelService: CodeTabelService) {
    this.loadCodeAdrestypes();
    this.loadCodeGemeenten();
    this.loadCodeLanden();
    console.log('min actief vanaf', this.minDateActiefVanaf);
  }

  /*
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.loadCodeAdrestypes();
    this.loadCodeGemeenten();
    this.loadCodeLanden();
  }
  */

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }


  public async handleFileInput(files: FileList) {
    this.fileToUpload = files.item(0);
  }

  savePersoneelslidAdres({ valid, value }: EloketForm<FlowbackPersoneelslidAdresForm>) {
    if (valid) {
      console.log("savePersoneelslidAdres", value);
      value.attest = this.fileToUpload;
      this.flowbackPersoneelslidAdresChange.emit(value);
    }
  }

  async HaalAttest(id: number) {
    //todo: implement
    //let bewijs = await this.flowbackService.GetFlowbackPersoneelslidAdresAttest(id).toPromise();
    let bewijs = null;
    let blob = convertByteArrayToBlob(bewijs.data.content, bewijs.data.contentType);
    FileSaver.saveAs(blob, bewijs.data.fileName.substr(9));

  }

  async DeleteAttest(id: number) {
    const confirmed = await this.confirmationService.promptConfirm('Personalia.Bank.VerwijderenAttestConfirm');
    if (confirmed) {
      //todo: implement
      //var deleted = await this.flowbackService.DeleteFlowbackPersoneelslidAdresAttest(id).toPromise();
      var deleted = true;
      if (deleted) {
        this.attestAanwezig = false;
      }
    }
  }

  async loadCodeAdrestypes() {
    this.codeAdrestypes = [];
    const codeAdrestypeDto = await this.codeTabelService.GetCodeAdrestypes().toPromise();
    this.codeAdrestypes = codeAdrestypeDto.map(item => new CodeAdrestype(item))
                                          .sort((a, b) => (b.omschrijving < a.omschrijving ? 1 : -1));

    this.codeAdrestypeSelectConfig = new ModelSelectConfig(this.codeAdrestypes,
                                                          codeAdrestype => codeAdrestype.codeAdrestypeId.toString(), 
                                                          codeAdrestype => codeAdrestype.omschrijving);
  }

  async loadCodeGemeenten() {
    this.codeGemeenten = [];
    const codeGemeenteDto = await this.codeTabelService.GetCodeGemeentes().toPromise();
    this.codeGemeenten = codeGemeenteDto.map(item => new CodeGemeente(item))
                                        .sort((a, b) => (b.postNrGemeente < a.postNrGemeente ? 1 : -1));

    this.codeGemeenteSelectConfig = new ModelSelectConfig(this.codeGemeenten,
                                                          codeGemeente => codeGemeente.codeGemeenteId.toString(), 
                                                          codeGemeente => codeGemeente.postNrGemeente.toString() + ' ' + codeGemeente.gemeente);

    this.loaded = true;
  }

  async loadCodeLanden() {
    this.codeLanden = [];
    const codeLandDto = await this.codeTabelService.GetCodeLanden().toPromise();
    this.codeLanden = codeLandDto.map(item => new CodeLand(item))
                                          .sort((a, b) => (b.naam < a.naam ? 1 : -1));

    this.codeLandSelectConfig = new ModelSelectConfig(this.codeLanden,
                                                        codeLand => codeLand.codeLandId.toString(), 
                                                        codeLand => codeLand.naam);
  }
}
```

adres-form-component.html:

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="savePersoneelslidAdres(f)">
    <div class="form-group row mb-3">
        <label class="col-4 col-form-label">van</label>
        <div class="col-8">
            <app-date-picker name="beginDatum" [minDate]="minDateActiefVanaf" ngModel></app-date-picker>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row mb-3">
        <label class="col-4 col-form-label">tot</label>
        <div class="col-8">
          <app-date-picker name="eindDatum" [minDate]="minDateActiefVanaf" ngModel></app-date-picker>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row mb-3">
        <label class="col-4 col-form-label">adrestype</label>
        <div class="col-8">
            <app-select name="codeAdresType" [selectConfig]="codeAdrestypeSelectConfig" ngModel>
            </app-select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row mb-3">
      <label class="col-4 col-form-label">Straatlijn</label>
      <div class="col-8">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="straatLijn" ngModel>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row mb-3">
        <label class="col-4 col-form-label">Straatlijn2</label>
        <div class="col-8">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="straatLijn2" ngModel>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row mb-3">
        <label class="col-4 col-form-label">Nummer</label>
        <div class="col-8">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="nummer" ngModel>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row mb-3">
        <label class="col-4 col-form-label">Bus</label>
        <div class="col-8">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="bus" ngModel>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row mb-3">
      <label class="col-4 col-form-label">Gemeente</label>
      <div class="col-8">
        <app-select name="codeGemeente" [selectConfig]="codeGemeenteSelectConfig" ngModel></app-select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row mb-3">
        <label class="col-4 col-form-label">Land</label>
        <div class="col-8">
            <app-select name="codeLand" [selectConfig]="codeLandSelectConfig" ngModel></app-select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row mb-3">
        <label class="col-4 col-form-label">Gebruiken als correspondentieadres?</label>
        <div class="col-8">
            <input type="checkbox" name="isCorrespondentie" ngModel>
            <label>Correspondentie</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row mb-3">
      <label translate="Personalia.Bank.Bewijs" class="col-4 col-form-label"></label>
      <div class="col-8">
        <ng-container *ngIf="attestAanwezig">
          <label>{{attest.naam}}</label>&nbsp;
          <button (click)="HaalAttest(attest.id)" class="btn btn-sm btn-light"><i class="far fa-file-pdf fa-2x"></i></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <button (click)="DeleteAttest(attest.id)" class="btn btn-sm btn-light"><i class="fal fa-trash-alt fa-2x"></i></button>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngIf="!attestAanwezig">
          <input type="file" id="file" (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)">
        </ng-container>
        
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <button class="btn btn-dark float-right" type="submit" [translate]="submitButtonText"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <app-global-form-error [error]="serverValidationError" [possibleErrors]="['AfwezigheidtypeYearsIncorrectOrder']"></app-global-form-error>
  </form>
```

wijzig-adres.component.html (edit address):

```
<h2>Adres wijzigen</h2>
<app-adres-form *ngIf="wijzigFlowbackPersoneelslidAdres && wijzigFlowbackPersoneelslidAdres.codeGemeenteId != null" submitButtonText="Button.Edit" [serverValidationError]="serverValidationError" [flowBackPersoneelslidAdres]="wijzigFlowbackPersoneelslidAdres" (flowbackPersoneelslidAdresChange)="onWijzigFlowbackPersoneelslidAdres($event)"></app-adres-form>
```

wijzig-adres.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-wijzig-adres',
  templateUrl: './wijzig-adres.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./wijzig-adres.component.scss']
})
export class WijzigAdresComponent implements OnInit {

  wijzigFlowbackPersoneelslidAdres: WijzigFlowbackPersoneelslidAdres;
  serverValidationError: ApiError;
  id: number;

  constructor(private flowbackService: FlowbackService, private notificationService: NotificationService,
    private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute, private routeParamsChange: RouteParamsChange) {
    this.routeParamsChange.watch(this.route, (params) => {
      this.id = params.id;
      this.loadData();
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  async loadData() {
    const flowbackPersoneelslidAdres = await this.flowbackService.GetFlowbackPersoneelslidAdresById(this.id).toPromise();
    this.wijzigFlowbackPersoneelslidAdres = new WijzigFlowbackPersoneelslidAdres(flowbackPersoneelslidAdres.data);

    console.log('load data in wijzig-adres component:', this.wijzigFlowbackPersoneelslidAdres);
  }

  async onWijzigFlowbackPersoneelslidAdres(flowback: FlowbackPersoneelslidAdresForm) {

    CatchFormError(this, async () => {

      const updateAdres: WijzigFlowbackPersoneelslidAdres = {
        id: this.id,
        straat: flowback.straatLijn,
        straatLijn2: flowback.straatLijn2,
        huisNummer: flowback.nummer,
        busNummer: flowback.bus,
        codeAdrestypeId: flowback.codeAdresType.codeAdrestypeId,
        codeGemeenteId: flowback.codeGemeente.codeGemeenteId,
        codeLandId: flowback.codeLand.codeLandId,
        beginDatum: flowback.beginDatum.format('MM/DD/YYYY'),
        eindDatum: flowback.eindDatum.format('MM/DD/YYYY'),
        isPrive: false,
        isCorrespondentie: flowback.isCorrespondentie
      };

      let objJsonStr = JSON.stringify(updateAdres);
      let objJsonB64 = Buffer.from(objJsonStr).toString("base64");

      await this.flowbackService.UpdateFlowbackPersoneelslidAdres({ flowback: objJsonB64, file: flowback.attest as any }).toPromise();
      this.notificationService.showMessage('Personalia.Bank.RekeningNummerGewijzigd');
      await this.router.navigate(['../../'], { relativeTo: this.route });
    });
  }

}
```

adres-overzicht.component.html (overview of addresses)

```
<app-master-detail [route]="route">
    <app-master>
      <div class="page">
        <div class="header">
            <h3>ADRESSEN</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="onderdeel-adres" *ngFor="let adres of Adressen; let i = index;">
                <table>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                      <h3>{{adres.adresType}}</h3>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="label"><label translate="Personalia.Adres.Van"></label></td>
                    <td class="inhoud">{{adres.beginDatum|date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="label"><label translate="Personalia.Adres.Tot"></label></td>
                    <td class="inhoud">
                      <ng-container *ngIf="!adres.eindDatum.startsWith('2999')">{{adres.eindDatum|date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</ng-container>
                      <ng-container *ngIf="adres.eindDatum.startsWith('2999')"><span translate="Personalia.Adres.Onbepaald"></span></ng-container>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="label"><label translate="Personalia.Adres.Straat"></label></td>
                    <td class="inhoud">{{adres.straat}}</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="label"><label translate="Personalia.Adres.Nr"></label></td>
                    <td class="inhoud">{{adres.huisnummer}}</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="label"><label translate="Personalia.Adres.Bus"></label></td>
                    <td class="inhoud">{{adres.busnummer}}</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="label"><label translate="Personalia.Adres.PostcodeGemeente"></label></td>
                    <td class="inhoud">{{adres.codeGemeente.postnrDeelGemeente}} {{adres.codeGemeente.deelGemeente}}</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="label"><label translate="Personalia.Adres.Land"></label></td>
                    <td class="inhoud">{{adres.codeLand.naam}}</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" class="inhoudCorAdres">&nbsp;<span *ngIf="adres.isCorrespondentie" translate="Personalia.Adres.Correspondentie"></span></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>                      
              </div>
              
              <ng-container *ngIf="flowBackAdresGegevens && flowBackAdresGegevens.length > 0">
                <div [ngClass]="{'onderdeel-flowback-adres':flowback.toestand !== 30, 'onderdeel-error-flowback-adres':flowback.toestand === 30}" *ngFor="let flowback of flowBackAdresGegevens; let i = index;">
                  <table>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="label"><label translate="">adrestype</label></td>
                    <td class="inhoud">{{ flowback.codeAdresType.omschrijving }}</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="label"><label translate="Personalia.Adres.Van"></label></td>
                    <td class="inhoud">{{ flowback.beginDatum | date:'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="label"><label translate="Personalia.Adres.Tot"></label></td>
                    <td class="inhoud">
                      <ng-container *ngIf="!flowback.eindDatum.startsWith('2999')">{{ flowback.eindDatum | date:'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</ng-container>
                      <ng-container *ngIf="flowback.eindDatum.startsWith('2999')"><span translate="Personalia.Adres.Onbepaald"></span></ng-container>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="label"><label translate="Personalia.Adres.Straat"></label></td>
                    <td class="inhoud">{{ flowback.straat }} {{ flowback.straatLijn2 }}</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="label"><label translate="Personalia.Adres.Nr"></label></td>
                    <td class="inhoud">{{ flowback.huisNummer }}</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="label"><label translate="Personalia.Adres.Bus"></label></td>
                    <td class="inhoud">{{ flowback.busNummer }}</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="label"><label translate="Personalia.Adres.PostcodeGemeente"></label></td>
                    <td class="inhoud">{{ flowback.codeGemeente.postnrDeelGemeente }} {{ flowback.codeGemeente.deelGemeente }}</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="label"><label translate="Personalia.Adres.Land"></label></td>
                    <td class="inhoud">{{ flowback.codeLand.naam }}</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="label"><label translate="">iscorrespondentie</label></td>
                    <td class="inhoud"><input type="checkbox" [checked]="flowback.isCorrespondentie" disabled="true"/></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="label"><label translate="">opmerking</label></td>
                    <td class="inhoud">{{ flowback.flowbackOpmerking }}</td>
                  </tr>
                  <!-- todo: only show opmerking when toestand = 30 (geweigerd?) -->
                  <tr *ngIf="flowback.toestand === 30">
                    <td class="label"><label translate="Personalia.Bank.Opmerking"></label></td>
                    <td class="inhoud">{{ flowback.flowbackOpmerking }}</td>
                  </tr>
                  <ng-container *ngIf="flowback.toestand !== 20">
                    <tr>
                      <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">
                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-light" (click)="OnEdit(flowback)"><i class="fal fa-edit fa-2x"></i></button>&nbsp;
                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-light" (click)="onDelete(flowback)"><i class="fal fa-trash-alt fa-2x"></i></button>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </ng-container>
                </table>
              </div>
            </ng-container>
            <!-- make sure the data arrived from the api before accessing it -->
            <ng-container *ngIf="Adressen && Adressen.length > 0">
              <div class="onderdeel-toevoegen">
                <table>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                      <h3><label translate="Personalia.Adres.Nieuw"></label></h3>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <app-date-picker [(ngModel)]="datumVanaf" [minDate]="datumVanaf"></app-date-picker>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <button [routerLink]="['nieuw', datumVanaf.format('MM/DD/YYYY'), Adressen[0].personeelslidId]"
                        translate="Personalia.Adres.Toevoegen" class="btn btn-dark"></button>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </div>
            </ng-container>

              <div class="onderdeel-waarschuwing">
                <label>Gegevens niet correct ?<br/><br/>Contacteer uw personeelsadviseur of dossierbeheerder</label>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </app-master>
    <app-detail>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </app-detail>
</app-master-detail>
```

adres-overzicht.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-adres-overzicht',
  templateUrl: './adres-overzicht.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./adres-overzicht.component.scss'],
  providers: [ChildRouteChanges, RouteParamsChange]
})
export class AdresOverzichtComponent implements OnInit {

  public Adressen: PersoneelslidAdres[];
  public datumVanaf: Moment;
  public flowBackAdresGegevens: FlowbackPersoneelslidAdres[];

  constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute, childRouteChanges: ChildRouteChanges, public router: Router,
    public personeelslidservice: PersoneelslidService, public flowbackService: FlowbackService,
    public confirmationService: ConfirmationService, public notificationService: NotificationService) { 
    this.datumVanaf = moment().add(1, 'M').startOf('month');

    childRouteChanges.watch(router, route, () => {
      this.loadPersoneelslidAdressen();
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadPersoneelslidAdressen();
  }

  async loadPersoneelslidAdressen() {
    let personeelslidAdresDto = await this.personeelslidservice.GetPersoneelslidAdres().toPromise();
    this.Adressen = personeelslidAdresDto.data;

    let flowbackPersoneelslidAdresDto = await this.flowbackService.GetFlowbackPersoneelslidAdres().toPromise();
    this.flowBackAdresGegevens = flowbackPersoneelslidAdresDto.data;
  }

  async OnEdit(flowback: FlowbackPersoneelslidAdres) {
    const id = flowback.id;
    console.log('id', flowback.id);
    this.router.navigate(['wijzig', id], { relativeTo: this.route });
  }

  async onDelete(flowback: FlowbackPersoneelslidAdres) {
    try { 
      const confirmed = await this.confirmationService.promptConfirm('Personalia.Adres.Flowback.VerwijderenConfirm', { beginDatum: apiStringToDate(flowback.beginDatum).format('DD/MM/YYYY')});
      if (confirmed) {
        await this.flowbackService.VerwijderFlowbackPersoneelslidAdres(flowback.id).toPromise();
        this.loadPersoneelslidAdressen();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      const { error } = e as ErrorEloket;

      if (!error.validationResult.isValid) {

        for (const err of error.validationResult.errors) {
          this.notificationService.showMessage(`Validatie.${ValidationError[err.error]}`, err.parameters);
        }
      }
    }

  }

}
```

model-select-config.ts:

```
import { Option } from './option';
import { SelectConfig } from './select-config';

export class ModelSelectConfig<T> implements SelectConfig<T> {
  public selectOptions: Option[];
  public options: T[];
  constructor(items: T[], public keySelector: (t: T) => string, textSelector: (t: T) => string) {
    this.options = items;
    this.selectOptions = items?.map(i => new Option(keySelector(i), textSelector(i)));
  }
}
```

select.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input, forwardRef, ViewChild, ElementRef, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ControlValueAccessor } from '@angular/forms';
import { SelectConfig } from './select-config';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-select',
  templateUrl: './select.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./select.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => SelectComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class SelectComponent<T> implements ControlValueAccessor {
  @ViewChild('select') select: ElementRef<HTMLSelectElement>;

  @Input() selectConfig: SelectConfig<T>;
  @HostBinding('class.read-only') @Input() readOnly: boolean;

  @Input() emptyTranslationKey: string;
  @Input() defaultValue: string;

  private onChange = (_: T) => { };
  public onTouched = () => { };

  constructor() {
 }

  selectedChange(key: string) {
    const { keySelector: keyFor } = this.selectConfig;
    const option = this.selectConfig.options.find(o => keyFor(o) === key);
    this.onChange(option);
  }

  writeValue(obj: T): void {
    if (!obj) { return; }
     //this fixes the issue
     /*
     setTimeout(() => {
      this.select.nativeElement.value = this.selectConfig.keySelector(obj);
    }, 100);
    */
    this.select.nativeElement.value = this.selectConfig.keySelector(obj);
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (option: T) => void): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.readOnly = isDisabled;
  }

  toggleSelect() {
    this.select.nativeElement.click();
  }
  
}
```

select.component.html:

```
<select class="form-control" #select (change)="selectedChange($event.target.value)"
  *ngIf="selectConfig" [disabled]="readOnly" [value]="defaultValue">
  <option disabled selected *ngIf="emptyTranslationKey" [value]="null" [translate]="emptyTranslationKey"></option>
  <option *ngFor="let option of selectConfig.selectOptions" [value]="option.key" [translate]="option.text"></option>
</select>
```

note that the line I added in comment in select.component.ts fixes the issue. However, this is not an acceptable solution as editing this file is a last go-to + this would delay all the code that uses this.

Anyone that has an idea what I can do in order to make this work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution** was to add a Subject with initial value of false, which is set true after the data is loaded from the api. Only then, the form data would be set, triggering the selects to be filled on the right time.

```
export interface FlowbackPersoneelslidAdresForm {

  straat: string;
  straatLijn2: string;
  huisNummer: number;
  busNummer: number;
  codeGemeente: CodeGemeente;
  codeAdresType: CodeAdrestype;
  codeLand: CodeLand;
  isCorrespondentie: boolean;
  beginDatum: moment.Moment;
  eindDatum: moment.Moment;
  attest: any;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-adres-form',
  templateUrl: './adres-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./adres-form.component.scss']
})

export class AdresFormComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('f', { static: true }) FlowbackPersoneelslidAdresForm: EloketForm<FlowbackPersoneelslidAdresForm>;

  @Input() serverValidationError: ValidationBag;

  @Input() submitButtonText: string;

  @Input() set flowBackPersoneelslidAdres(value: FlowbackPersoneelslidAdres) {
    if (!value) {
      return;
    }

//only set form values after the data is loaded from the api because it was being accessed in select-component before it arrived
    this.dataLoaded.subscribe(loaded => {
      if(loaded){
          setFormValue(this.FlowbackPersoneelslidAdresForm, {
            straat: value.straat,
            straatLijn2: value.straatLijn2,
            huisNummer: value.huisNummer,
            busNummer: value.busNummer,
            codeAdresType: value.codeAdresType,
            codeGemeente: value.codeGemeente,
            codeLand: value.codeLand,
            beginDatum: moment(value.beginDatum),
            eindDatum: moment(value.eindDatum),
            isCorrespondentie: value.isCorrespondentie,
            attest: value.flowbackPersoneelslidAdresAttest
          });
          if (value.flowbackPersoneelslidAdresAttest) {
            this.attestAanwezig = true;
            this.attest = new FlowbackPersoneelslidAdresAttest(value.flowbackPersoneelslidAdresAttest);
          }
      }
    });

    }
      
  @Output() public flowbackPersoneelslidAdresChange = new EventEmitter<FlowbackPersoneelslidAdresForm>();

  minDateActiefVanaf: moment.Moment = moment(new Date());
  codeAdrestypeSelectConfig: ModelSelectConfig<CodeAdrestype>;
  codeAdrestypes: CodeAdrestype[];

  codeGemeenteSelectConfig: ModelSelectConfig<CodeGemeente>;
  codeGemeenten: CodeGemeente[];

  codeLandSelectConfig: ModelSelectConfig<CodeLand>;
  codeLanden: CodeLand[];

  fileToUpload: File = null;
  attestAanwezig: boolean = false;
  attest: FlowbackPersoneelslidAdresAttest;

  loaded: boolean = false;

  //added Subject<boolean>
  dataLoaded = new Subject<boolean>();

  constructor(private confirmationService: ConfirmationService, private codeTabelService: CodeTabelService) {

    //do these methods in order, make sure that loadCodeLanden is the last one, then set loaded boolean in loadCodeLanden
    this.loadCodeAdrestypes()
      .then(() => {
        return this.loadCodeGemeenten();
        })
        .then(() => {
          return this.loadCodeLanden();
          });

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  public async handleFileInput(files: FileList) {
    this.fileToUpload = files.item(0);
  }

  savePersoneelslidAdres({ valid, value }: EloketForm<FlowbackPersoneelslidAdresForm>) {
    if (valid) {
      console.log("savePersoneelslidAdres", value);
      value.attest = this.fileToUpload;
      this.flowbackPersoneelslidAdresChange.emit(value);
    }
  }

  async HaalAttest(id: number) {
    //todo: implement
    let bewijs = null;
    let blob = convertByteArrayToBlob(bewijs.data.content, bewijs.data.contentType);
    FileSaver.saveAs(blob, bewijs.data.fileName.substr(9));

  }

  async DeleteAttest(id: number) {
    const confirmed = await this.confirmationService.promptConfirm('Personalia.Bank.VerwijderenAttestConfirm');
    if (confirmed) {
      //todo: implement
      var deleted = true;
      if (deleted) {
        this.attestAanwezig = false;
      }
    }
  }

  async loadCodeAdrestypes() {
    this.codeAdrestypes = [];
    const codeAdrestypeDto = await this.codeTabelService.GetCodeAdrestypes().toPromise();
    this.codeAdrestypes = codeAdrestypeDto.map(item => new CodeAdrestype(item))
                                          .sort((a, b) => (b.omschrijving < a.omschrijving ? 1 : -1));

    this.codeAdrestypeSelectConfig = new ModelSelectConfig(this.codeAdrestypes,
                                                          codeAdrestype => codeAdrestype.codeAdrestypeId.toString(), 
                                                          codeAdrestype => codeAdrestype.omschrijving);
  }

  async loadCodeGemeenten() {
    this.codeGemeenten = [];
    const codeGemeenteDto = await this.codeTabelService.GetCodeGemeentes().toPromise();
    this.codeGemeenten = codeGemeenteDto.map(item => new CodeGemeente(item))
                                        .sort((a, b) => (b.postNrGemeente < a.postNrGemeente ? 1 : -1));

    this.codeGemeenteSelectConfig = new ModelSelectConfig(this.codeGemeenten,
                                                          codeGemeente => codeGemeente.codeGemeenteId.toString(), 
                                                          codeGemeente => codeGemeente.postNrGemeente.toString() + ' ' + codeGemeente.gemeente);

  }

  async loadCodeLanden() {
    this.codeLanden = [];
    const codeLandDto = await this.codeTabelService.GetCodeLanden().toPromise();
    this.codeLanden = codeLandDto.map(item => new CodeLand(item))
                                          .sort((a, b) => (b.naam < a.naam ? 1 : -1));

    this.codeLandSelectConfig = new ModelSelectConfig(this.codeLanden,
                                                        codeLand => codeLand.codeLandId.toString(), 
                                                        codeLand => codeLand.naam);

    //set Subject<boolean> to true
    this.dataLoaded.next(true);

  }
}
```